# Which distribution for modelling duration of tasks?

Tags: distributions, estimation

Recently I was present with a task estimation technique. Instead of letting people rate a task for x - amount of hours, I let them discretize tasks into discrete sizes like small / medium / large / x-large. (The tasks are planning poker from scrum for people aware of this.)

After a bit of tracking we should be able to estimate the duration based upon historical data (i.e. statistics). I have been given a set of sample data (real data, but not from my work) and would like see there actually can be made any distribution which fit this. (Of course, I would need to recalculate this for my own tasks.)

The distributions from the presentations look like this:

[image]

It seem like some right skewed distribution. From University, I recall working with a distribution looking like this, but I am not certain about the name. I was hoping for something parametric where I can derive some simple parameters form the data (like mean and variance for a normal distribution)

I have made a histogram of the data:

[image]

(I know there are too few data.)

Comment: Not sure if this is useful, but survival/event history/time before failure models are used to answer the dual questions of *whether and when an event occurs*. By asking about *duration* are you trying to answer *whether and when a task is completed*? If so  a survival/event history/time before failure model might be useful.

Answer (score 13):

Some choices include [Weibull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution), [Gamma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution) (including exponential), and [lognormal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution) distributions, possibly with a shift-parameter if there's a non-zero minimum possible time. (However from your diagram it looks like there's also potentially a discreteness issue.)

If the presentation drawing is reasonably accurate, a [shift-parameter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Location_parameter) will probably be required.

If there's a tendency for the times to be highly skew, log-logistic, inverse Gaussian or Pareto might be considered. (It doesn't look to be the case here though.)

Comment: Thanks for suggestions!
Regarding the discreteness issue: I choose some bins for the histogram 1-5, 5-10... and etc.

Answer (score 5):

You might want to try an [Erlang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlang_distribution) distribution. Here are a couple of excerpts from the page:

> The distribution is a continuous distribution, which has a positive value for all real numbers greater than zero, and is given by two parameters: the shape $k$, which is a positive integer, and the rate $\lambda$, which is a positive real number
>
> Events that occur independently with some average rate are modeled with a Poisson process. The waiting times between $k$ occurrences of the event are Erlang distributed.

I am not sure if there is a good intuitive explanation about why Erlang would fit here but I'll give it a shot: if you think of each task consisting of smaller subtasks, then you can model this in three ways:

1. Each subtask takes about same amount of time (so using the notation of the Wikipedia page,  the $\mu$ is the same for all tasks but the larger estimates have higher number of subtasks (the $k$ in the Erlang formula).
2. The converse: each size task has the same number of subtasks but each subtask is longer.
3. A combination of (1) and (2).

Just be careful in fitting that you have enough historical data to build a decent model without overfitting and kudos to you for applying statistics to Scrum project estimation!